# What is the right forms of verbs in brackets?

Tags: past-tense

1. Finally, the ship  (move). Peter could relax at last.
2. What  (he do) when he first saw her? He couldn't remember.

   In the first sentence I, think it can be past perfect because the ship firstly had moved and then Peter could relax, but also it can be past simple (the ship moved and Peter could relax) to show that one action is followed by another one. So I don't know what to choose. And in the 2nd sentence it can be past simple or past continuous.

Comment: Could you tell us what *you* think the right answers are and why?

Comment: In the first sentence I think it can past perfect because the ship firstly had moved and then Peter could relax, but also it can be past simple (the ship moved and Peter could relax) to show that one action is followed by another one. So I don't know what to choose. And in the 2nd sentence it can be past simple or past continuous.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, questions which could be answered by a dictionary or other similar basic research are off-topic on this site. If you have found an answer but it confuses you in some way, please detail the research and what you are unsure about. Basically, we aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Since *saw* is used, this is in the past tense. However, there are several different past tenses that could be used. It's not possible to definitively pick one over the others. And simply listing all possible versions is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Because this looks a whole lot like the kind of homework assignment questions I used to get when I was studying English, I'll give the answers I think are "expected" here.

> Finally, the ship **moved**. Peter could relax at last.

It sounds like Peter was anxious because the ship wasn't moving. But, after waiting for it to move for a while, it finally **did**. This is an example of telling a story where, as you say, one action follows another. Here's another example:

> The burglar **crawled** through the kitchen window and **started** looking for the safe where the family kept their money. He **was** very careful not to make a sound, but he **didn't** know the house had a very expensive system. So when he **entered** the guest bedroom, the alarm **went off** with a loud shriek.

As for your second sentence, there is more than one option, but I'd imagine the assignment writers expected:

> What **was he doing** when he first saw her? He couldn't remember.

Here, the idea is that an event in the past interrupted something in progress. Maybe he **was reading** a newspaper at a cafe, or **walking** home from work, but in the middle of that, he **saw** "her". He just can't remember.

You could also say:

> What **did he do** when he first saw her? He couldn't remember.

This means that he *reacted* to seeing her by actually doing something. Maybe he **said** hello, or **spilled** coffee on himself because he was distracted by how pretty she was. He just can't remember. The difference with the first version is that the focus changes from what he was already doing before he saw her, to what he did when he saw her.